# differential operators operate to the right correct?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

More of a grammar question here i guess? I think this acts on the argument to its right? so in a situation like $\ z^s \frac d{dz} z^{-s} · J_s(z) $ the derivitive acts to the term on the right of the operator correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle yes, it acts on the next term to the right. Physicists have an arrow notation to let a differential operator act to the left

And are you sure that you did mean this
$$\ z^s \frac d{dz} z^{-s} · J_s(z) = -s·z^{-1}·J_s(z)  $$
or was this expression intended
$$\ z^s \frac d{dz} \left( z^{-s} · J_s(z)\right)  
= -s·z^{-1}·J_s(z) + \frac d{dz} J_s(z)$$

---

Groupings are important in mathematics, that's why there is a very long and interesting history of grouping notations with parts of long gone conventions remaining in the current notation.

---

And learn LaTeX, it is not only important here but generally helps with mathematical texts.

Comment: yeah I meant the differential to act just on the one factor. Thanks!